# Prove that if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and has a local minimum at $x=x_0$ then $f'(x_0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I am asked to prove:

If $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and has a local minimum at $x=x_0$ then $f'(x_0)=0$, where $f'(x_0)$ indicates the derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=x_0$

Would I have to use the local extremum theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ being differentiable at a point $x_0$ means that the limit
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}
$$
exists. Now, if $x_0$ is in the interior of the domain of $f$, use the fact that $x_0$ is a local minimum to argue about the sign of the two limits
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}
$$

Comment: Isn't needed to require that $x_0$ is an interior point of the domain for the two limits being meaningful?

Comment: @enzotib Some let that be implicit as part of the definition of "differentiable at $x_0$". For instance, there are many times I've heard statements along the lines of "Let $f:[a, b]\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function that is differentiable on $(a, b)$."

Comment: @Arthur that statement you've heard does not "let that be implicit as part of the definition of [differentiability at a point]". Anyway in the context of this post I think it is imperative to make this hypothesis on $x_0$ explicit in the statement of the theorem, to avoid its misuses.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, I can include an assumption that $x_0$ is in the interior.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f'(x_0)\neq 0$ (say $f'(x_0) >0$, for example). What is guaranteed to happen in any neighbourhood of $x_0$?

(Drawing $f(x)$ with the tangent line at $x_0$ can help)